# Single query to SELECT NOW() then format it and UPDATE value

Tags: php, postgresql, datetime

is it possible to do following with just single query in postgresql?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT NOW()');
$data = $stmt->execute();

$currentTime = new DateTime($data['now']);
$currentTime = $currentTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE my_table SET my_time = :time');
$stmt->execute(array('time'=>$currentTime);
```

What I am trying to do:

- I would like to do everything in one update query (select NOW() then format it and set it as new value)
- I need to use function NOW() not timestamp
- I need to save the time in format without timezone ('Y-m-d H:i:s')

Comment: So to make sure, all you want to do is get the current time and update my_time in 'Y-m-d H:i:s' form?

Comment: yes, that's it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this for MySQL `UPDATE my_table SET my_time = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-%m-%d H:%i:%s")` or just use whatever format you need check the list in here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

And this for postgresql `UPDATE my_table SET my_time = to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` and use this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: that's it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Use in your update statement

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_time = NOW()
```

You don't have to fetch a date previously. You can use this MySQL function directly in your update statement.

If the web server and mysql server are on the same server you can also do it like this, if the mysql format is not your favourite:

```
'UPDATE my_table SET my_time = '. date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
```

Just set the correct time zone you want to.

Comment: MySQL uses only formatted times. Timestamps are not automatically used be MySQL I think.

Comment: Is there any difference for postgresql?

Comment: There should be no differences to postgreesql. Interesting article for this: http://postgresguide.com/tips/dates.html